# Dynamically loading unique components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, components

I am seeking information as to the feasibility to dynamically instantiate and render unique components in Angular 2. Specifically, a service call from the root component would return a JSON object with key value pairs, representing a given component and whether that component should be rendered.  An example of the JSON could be:

```
  {"components":[{"AccountingComp":true},
                 {"PayrollComp":true}, 
                 {"InvoicingComp":false}
                ]
  }
```

(this is an example of what could be 10+ components)

Ideally, not everyone component would be instantiated, just to have it's visibility turned off.  But just those components required to be displayed, be instantiated.  Thus, how do I instantiate those components programmatically (AccountingComp, PayrollComp)?  And associate those components to the DOM for rendering?

Any examples or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: See the plnkr posted [here](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=55f35be78825e1c87c9bcb23)

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's exactly what I was looking for!